# AVCaptureDevice keeps crashing my iPod Touch with OS 3

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I made some conditional coding in my app to check for AVCaptureDevice, but it still crashes my iPod Touch (iOS 3.1.3) with this message:

dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice

Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/4286D40F-9E33-49AB-9AD9-4F66EB9331A5/TestApp.app/TestApp

Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation

Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)

mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack.

mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack.

In my code, I do conditional checks like this:

```
#if (!TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000 // __IPHONE_4_0
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    // ... more code
#endif
#endif
```

I'm checking here and the other place in code that uses AVCaptureDevice with this same conditional.

I'm guessing the iPods older iOS version isn't able to link to the newer library, so I how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot use preprocessor directives to select which code to run here. The check has to happen at runtime, not at compile time. So you must use `NSClassFromString()`, `-respondsToSelector:` or similar techniques to do this.

Second, to make this compile, change your compiler to LLVM GCC [as described by Marco Arment](http://www.marco.org/1648550153).

Comment: It seems strange that I would need to use a different compiler to make an app compatible with older OS versions.  Is this the ONLY way?

Comment: You can also use the `NSClassFromString` technique that has always worked. It's just more cumbersome. And LLVM is the better compiler (and the future) anyway so you might as well make the switch now.

Comment: I tried the NSClassFromString and still get the error: id cls = (NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice")); if( cls != nil ) { // ... I've cleaned the targets, deleted the app from the device, ran it, and still the same problem persists.  Right at app start I make this check and set a flag to prevent use later in the app.  However, my NSLog statements never even get to this check.

Comment: When I comment out the two places in my code that reference AVCaptureDevice, the code works.  If I uncomment the code, and place it in an unreachable block, I still get the error.

Comment: I you want to do it that way, you must nowhere call a method on the class directly. `Class myClass = NSClassFromString(...); id myInstance = [[myClass alloc] init...];`

Comment: Thank you sir, you are my savior!  I can see how this would be a major pain to work with in a different situation from mine - will look into LLVM.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking if you have AVfoundation.framework added to your Frameworks
In my opinion, it's the most probable reason for the error

Answer (score 1):

AVCaptureDevice is only available on iOS versions 4 and above. You have two options:

1. Check the system version and handle things appropriately:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
if([device.systemVersion floatValue]
    NSLog(@"Not supported on this software version");
}else{

//Proceed Normally
}
```

1. Check for class availablility:

```
Class avcaptureclass = (NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice"));

if (avCaptureClass != nil){
    //Proceed Normally
}else{
    NSLog(@"Not supported on this software version.");
}
```

Comment: I tried both of your statements above, and with both I still get the same error.